# AVIcode versus AppFabric

Tags: appfabric, avicode

I just learned today about the [System Center AVIcode](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/en/us/avicode.aspx) product, which is a .net application monitoring tool. I don't know much about it and I was wondering how it would compare to [AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849). The latter also has monitoring features as well as other useful features. How much do these two product overlap and for which scenario is each one better suited?

Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Sight is applicable only to .NET framework 4.0 in terms on monitoring WCF transactions and Workflows. It's integrated into IIS Mgr thru extensions.

AVICode monitors a more broader range of .NET frameworks and protocols and is available as standalone or through integration with SCOM.

So the overlap would be the visibility they both provide for apps that leverage WCF and Workflows.

If you're interested in .NET application monitoring you might want to checkout http://www.appdynamics.com/. We're currently in the middle of our .NET beta program and have had a great response so far from users. I can sign you up for a no hassle free trial if you want to have a play and see what visibility we can provide . Drop me a line at appman@appdynamics.com if your keen.

Answer (score 3):

AVIcode (now simply called "APM" feature in System Center 2012 - Operations Manager) and AppDynamics are monitoring products playing in the same space/market.

They both provide visibility into code-level performance issues with your application. If you are interested in AVIcode technology you can watch my talk at TechEd 2012 to see APM in Operations Manager in action http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2012/MGT302

AppFabric provides hosting and activation services, so it is orthogonal to the above - while it provides some "infrastructure" monitoring capability (i.e. the host running your code being up or down) it doesn't go to the code level showing "what was slow" or "what threw exceptions" in your code.